# Inconsistent y range and font while using subplot

Tags: python, subplot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g71Ra.png)

As shown in the image, I am trying to generate figures in subplot fashion for different electrcial parameters. However the yrange is keep changing. Any idea how to resolve this.

This is the code I am using.

```
def plot_subplots(Monitor_Channels,subTitle,**kwarg):
    outfiles  = glob.glob(os.getcwd() + "\PSSE_Data" + "/*.csv")
    if len(Monitor_Channels)!= 0:
       for outfile in outfiles:
           for k,j in enumerate(range(0, len(Monitor_Channels),6)):
               chunk = Monitor_Channels[j:j+6]
               for n, chans in enumerate(chunk):
                   df = pd.read_csv(outfile, usecols=['Time', chans],index_col = False, header=0)
                   chan_name = chans
                   t = df['Time'].values
                   chan_data = df[chans].values
                   if "FREQ" in chan_name:
                      chan_data = 50*(1+ chan_data)
                   fig = plt.figure(str(os.path.basename(outfile[:-4]) + str(subTitle)),linewidth=0.5,figsize=(8,12))
                   fig.suptitle(str(os.path.basename(outfile[:-4])), fontsize=title_font,y=1.0)
                   nrows = len(chunk)
                   if len(chunk)%2 != 0:
                      ncols_sub =1
                   else:
                      ncols_sub =2
#                    fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.8)
                   ax = plt.subplot(nrows, ncols_sub, n + 1)
                   ax.grid(which='major', color='#DDDDDD', linewidth=0.7)
                   ax.grid(which='minor', color='#EEEEEE', linestyle=':', linewidth=0.4)
                   ax.minorticks_on()
                   ax.plot(t,chan_data,linestyle='-', linewidth=1,color= "blue",  label=chan_name)
                   ax.set_ylabel(Naming_Ylabels(chan_name), fontsize=Y_font)
                   ax.legend(fontsize=3.5)
                   plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), fontsize= 4)
                   plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), fontsize= 4)
                   axes = plt.gca()
                   axes.set_xlim([t[0],t[-1]])
                   for key, value in kwarg.items():
                       if key == 'ylim':
                          axes.set_ylim([value[0],value[1]])
                       if key == 'xlim':
                          axes.set_xlim([value[0],value[1]])
                   axes.legend(loc='best',prop={'size':3.5}, ncol = 2)
                   ax.set_xlabel('Time [s]', fontsize=X_font)
               plt.tight_layout(h_pad=0.1)
               plt.savefig(str(k)+"_"+ str(os.path.basename(outfile[:-4]))+ "_" + str(subTitle) + ".pdf" ,bbox_inches='tight')
               plt.close()
    else:
        print "No channels available to plot !"
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it but adding one extra line.

plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False) # this will prevent subplot plots to have exponential range